# how to show sql error message in a javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have a code which insert some values into a database table. It is working properly. I wont to get errors like database connecting errors,duplicate entry. Here is my code.
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
<body>
<?php
require '../classes/dbconnect.php';

$PId=$_POST["PatientId"];
$pName=$_POST["NameOfPatient"];
$age=$_POST["AgeOfPatient"];
$lId=$_SESSION['username'];
$fbs=$_POST["FBS"];
$sc=$_POST["Serum"];
$bu=$_POST["urea"];
$sgot=$_POST["sgot"];
$sgpt=$_POST["sgpt"];
$sa=$_POST["SAP"];
$sp=$_POST["protein"];
$sea=$_POST["albumin"];
$globulin=$_POST["globulin"];
$date=$_POST["date"];
$_SESSION['FBS'] = $fbs;


$db = new Database("localhost", "root", "", "mlab");
$x = $db->insert("INSERT INTO blood_report VALUES
('$PId','$lId','$date','$pName','$age','$fbs','$sc','$bu','$sgot','$sgpt','$s    a','$sp','$sea','$globulin')");

if($x == 1){
    header("Location:../bloodreport.php");
}else{
    $str = "error :" . $db->err();
    ?>
    <script>
    var erro= '<?php echo "error :" . $db->err(); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
    //echo $str;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Duplicate entry");history.go(-1);</script>';
}
echo $x;

?>
```

Comment: You're not using $str ?

Comment: I used it. But not working

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Duplicate entry"+erro);history.go(-1);</script>';

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
......
if($x == 1){
   header("Location:../bloodreport.php");
}else{
   $str = "error :" . $db->err();
   ?>
<script>
    var erro= <?php echo '"error : '  . $db->err() . '"';  ?>;
</script>
......
```

Comment: @IsuruSandamal Make sure that $db->err() returns a string

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each critical statement in try...catch block and logging error.

```
try {
$db = new Database("localhost", "root", "", "mlab");
} catch (Exception $e) {
$errString = $e->getMessage(); 
}

try {
    $x = $db->insert("INSERT INTO blood_report VALUES
('$PId','$lId','$date','$pName','$age','$fbs','$sc','$bu','$sgot','$sgpt','$s    a','$sp','$sea','$globulin')");
} catch (Exception $e) {
$errString = $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

**EDIT**
Later do :

```
<?php if (isset($errString) && $errString !== '') { ?>
<script>
var error = "<?php echo 'error : ' . $errString; ?>";
alert(error);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Also validate post before insertion http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php